# R: solving non linear equation using optimise

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

So im trying to solve an equation that have 3 unknown factor. I decided to use nlm.

I defined my function F that take 3 parameters that are put in a vector, and what im trying to find is the vetor X that verify the following equation :

> F(X)-F(X1)-F(X2)-F(X3)=0

so I applied nlm to the LHS. but i get some weird results, instead of having a solution that  make the LHS close to zero, it give solution that make the LHS converge to -infinite

Can anyone point me to the right direction.

Thank you all in advance :)

```
rm(list=ls())
Ta <- 30 #commun parameter
c <- 0.09 #commun parameter

Delta_T <- c( 10, 20, 30 ) #vector containing X1(1), X2(1) and X3(1)
tetha <- c( 0.9, 1.1, 1.5 ) #vector containing X1(2), X2(2) and X3(2)
t <- c( 300, 400, 100 ) 
N <- t/tetha #vector containing X1(3), X2(3) and X3(3)

F <- function(X){ #definition of function F
  x <- X[1] 
  y <- X[2]
  N <- X[3]
  N*(min(c(y,2))/2)^1/3*x^1.9*exp(-1414/(x+Ta+273))*(1+c*(x/20)^2.1*(2/min(y,2))^1/3)
}

S <- vector("numeric",length(t))  #creation of F(X1) F(X2) and F(X3)
for (i in 1:length(t)) {
  S[i]=F(c(Delta_T[i],tetha[i],N[i]))
}

Eq <- function(X){  #creation of F(X)-F(X1)-F(X2)-F(X3)
  F(X)-sum(S)}
p <- c(min(Delta_T),min(tetha),min(N))

Sol = nlm(Eq,p)
```

EDIT : so I found the solution to the problem, instead of writing

```
Eq <- function(X){  #creation of F(X)-F(X1)-F(X2)-F(X3)
  F(X)-sum(S)}
```

I applied abs() to the function Eq

```
Eq <- function(X){  #creation of F(X)-F(X1)-F(X2)-F(X3)
      abs(F(X)-sum(S)) }
```

I dont get satisfying results doe, the error is close to 0 but X[2] is way bigger then 2 because of the min(2,X[2])

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In your question, it would be helpful if you explained what the unexpected behavior is, your weird results, and what the expected behavior is.

Comment: When you say RHS you most likely mean the Left Hand Side instead i.e. LHS because the RHS of your equation is fixed and zero.

Comment: I fixed the errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution to this problem, instead of using the function `nlm` to solve my non linear equation, I used the function `auglag` from the package `nloptr`.

```
Eq <- function(X){  #creation of F(X)-F(X1)-F(X2)-F(X3)
  F(X)-sum(S)}
p <- c(min(Delta_T),min(tetha),min(N))

Sol = auglag(p,Eq,hin = Eq)
```

`auglag` is a very strong non linear optimization algorithme. And the results are very satisfying as i get an error 10e-7